# How to set and read a version in an ArcGIS Pro AddIn-File?

Tags: c#, add-in, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am creating a c# AddIn for ArcGIS Pro 3.1. As there are a lot of users I want to use our deployment tool.

This tool works with the version of the file to check if there is a need to deploy a new version.

In the .esriAddinX-File which is created I cannot see any versioninfo.

Is there a way to add a version-number to this file or is there any other mechanism I can use?

Working with the File-creation-date and/or the File-changed-Date is not a prefered way as its quite error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .esriAddinX file is in fact a .zip file, and it contains a copy of Config.daml.

If your deployment tool can open zip files, it could extract that file, and read the version information from it.

Answer (score 1):

I've yet to do any .Net AddIn development for ArcGIS Pro but I used to do a lot in ArcMap. The version information, name, company and description of an AddIn was all in the DAML section of the tool. For ArcGIS Pro more information can be found in the [Introduction to DAML (Desktop Application Markup Language)](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProConcepts-Framework#introduction-to-daml-desktop-application-markup-language).

Comment: Yes, there is some AddIn-Info (A version too) in the config.daml-file. But the result of building a is a .esriAddinX-File where I cant find any Version info.